# not getting a token from getIdToken() but when i display document data it shows accessToken

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
  const user = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  };
  let errors = {};
  if (isEmpty(user.email)) {
    errors.email = "Must not be empty";
  }
  if (isEmpty(user.password)) {
    errors.password = "Must not be empty";
  }

  if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    })

//Problem this is working and showing json objecct with token
//    .then((data) => {
//      return res.status(201).json(data);
//    })
//If i fetch token in place of whole json object is show empty while
//the tutorial i am following gets token like this
.then((data) => {
      return res.status(201).json({token:data.user.getIdToken()});
    })

    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: "User not registered" });
      } else if (err.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
        return res
          .status(403)
          .json({ message: "email and password doesnot match" });
      } else return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
});
```

help me please this document data has uid and if you console it will show token but i can not access idToken from it using getIdToken thats why my code is giving errors if some one can help 
The access email is momin@gmail.com and password is 123456 you can call api to check the data

Comment: Please explain what you expect the code to do. There are a lot of variables here that we can't see, so it's hard to tell what should happen.  I suggest using the UID of the user to create a per-user document, not some name that they've chosen for themselves.

Comment: i need the code to create an authentication user and after that i need to fetch uid from authentication user and create an doc in db

Comment: Yes, I see that.  Since there are a lot of variables in your code, it's impossible to imagine how you are invoking this code and what exactly you expect to happen as a result.  The code you are showing is also incomplete.  I suggest adding some log statements to verify that each stage is working as you expect, and each variable contains the values you expect.

Comment: it add the data to db is i dont have userId field in userCredentials i dont know maybe i can not fetch uid from the authentication user i need help with that

Answer (score 0):

`firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` is a method of the [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) and not of the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth).

In a Cloud Function you have to use the Admin SDK, and in particular the Admin SDK's [`createUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#createuser) method.

Also, note that by doing

```
  db.collection("users")
    .doc(newUser.userHandle)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
       //....
    })
    .then((data) => {
      userId = data.user.uid;
      return res.json({ data: data.user.getIdToken() });
    })
```

you are probably terminating your HTTP Cloud Function, see the [Cloud Function doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions) as well as the [Express doc](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json). So the rest of your code will not be executed in the majority of the cases.

---

I would suggest you watch the three Firebase videos about "JavaScript Promises" presented by Doug: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: i figured out something if i dont write data.user.getIdToken() rest of the code works it like i am not getting a promise token back from firebase the getIdToken() is only returning {} if i remove that the code works

Comment: If you have adapted your code, please edit your question and add the new code.